# My C program doesn`t work unless I add a printf before everything else

Tags: c

I tried to run the code and it terminates and doesn`t print anything, but if I include a printf statement as the first line in the main, it works. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node TNode;
typedef struct list TList;

struct list{
    TNode *node;
};

struct node{
    int data;
    TNode *next;
};

TList* buildList(){
    TList *list;
    list = (TList*)malloc(sizeof(TList));
    list->node->next = NULL;
    printf("\nList was built successfully\n");
    return list;
}


int main(){
    TList *myList = buildList();
    myList->node->data = 5;
    printf("\nData: %d\n", myList->node->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mylist->node` is not allocated, your code working after adding a `printf` is a fluke

Comment: list->node = (TNode*)malloc(sizeof(TNode));  in buildlist

Comment: `node` is a bad name for the member of `strict list`. Is it the head node or the tail node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `list->node->next` without having initialized `list->node`. Allocate memory for the node and assign a pointer to it to `list->node`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node TNode;
typedef struct list TList;

struct list{
    TNode *node;
};

struct node{
    int data;
    TNode *next;
};

TList* buildList(){
    TList *list;
    list = (TList*)malloc(sizeof(TList));
    list->node = (TNode*)malloc(sizeof(TNode));    // <---
    list->node->next = NULL;
    printf("\nList was built successfully\n");
    return list;
}


int main(){
    TList *myList = buildList();
    myList->node->data = 5;
    printf("\nData: %d\n", myList->node->data);
    return 0;
}
```